How to get one program's audio to stream to my mic?
I am trying to get one programs audio to my microphone input. Basically, I want to be able to stream one programs audio through the mic while also still being able to talk through it.
However, I don't want the other programs I have running also streaming through the mic.
I know you're supposed to do this with virtual audio cables and Voicemeeter, but I tried and even with a YT tutorial and reading a few sources I didn't know where to start.
In the audio settings there are also like 10 inputs / outputs which doesn't help.
Does someone know what I need to do in this case?

(I am not asking for a specific program, just some pointers on how to use Voicemeeter, so I think this is on topic here)

Steps so far:

I've installed Voicemeeter (the most basic version), and ran the program.
At the top left of the program, you can select your hardware inputs. I selected my microphone.
On the far right, there is a few dropdown menus. Under A1, I selected my headphones.

Those are all of the steps I've done so far, but any further actions didn't obtain the result I was hoping for. I was able to play all desktop audio to my mic, but again, that's not the desired result.
NOTE: I will be adding screenshots when I can; I thought I'd add this part until I can add the pictures.

Yes, VB-Audio VoiceMeeter and alternatives, https://alternativeto.net/software/voicemeeter/, should be able to do what you want. Admittedly, some of these utilities are not easy to configure. Show screenshots of what you've tried.

What are the inputs? What are the outputs? General tips are off topic: we deal with specific questions that can get specific answers, so please add some specificity to your question to help us better help you.

@music2myear Yeah I see what you mean. I will be adding some more information soon.

@music2myear I've made an edit to hopefully outline some of what I've done so far. Like the edit says, I will be adding screenshots soon.
